# Put comma after certain characters

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a requirement to put a comma after every 300 characters.

I am trying this approach :

```
select regexp_replace(column_name, '(...){300}', '\1,') 
from table_name ;
```

But this is not working .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(COLUMN_NAME, '(.{300})', '\1,')
```

What you have right now would search for 300 occurrences of a group of any three characters, replacing that with the last group of that 300 and a comma.

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score -2):

```
select SUBSTR(column_name, 1, 300) || ',' || SUBSTR(column_name, 301) from table_name ;
```

Comment: This only deals with the first 300 characters, not every set of 300. It also adds a comma even if there are fewer than 300 characters.